# Xamarin Forms ListView Horizontal and then Vertical items

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

i am beginning my adventure in xamarin forms and i was wondering if its possible to create a listview with items going horizontal and then vertical like the image below:

[image]

I don't think its possible via the ListView control as I could not find an ItemContainerStyle like in WPF. Does any one have a good idea about how to implement this kind of functionality in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Have a look at the `FlowListView` component. That has the ability to do what you want! You can find it here; https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

Comment: Or [GridView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/GridView)

Comment: hmm both seem nice, thanks, will try them out and share my experience, thanks!

Comment: You could use a normal Listview and add a CustomCell which contains a vertical scrollview. That would allow you to scroll the whole listview vertical but each cell horizontal too. In the scrollview you can add whatever you want if the scrollview contains e.g.  stacklayout with `Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal`

Comment: You can have an ordinary ListView with some Columns within it and place the elements in different Columns .